# I need a delay when I change some text

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I need a hint! I want to change some text with a delay in it. With `.delay` it isn't working because it isn't a queue. Then I tried it with `.setTimeout`. That worked, but only for one textbox. When I add another one, it doesn't work properly. Can anyone help me?

Here the code:

```
$('#text-box1').hover(function() {
     $('#text-box1').text("The text changed!");
}, function() {
     $('#text-box1').text("The previous Text");
});
```

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context...

Comment: so you are using differnet functions for different text boxes like #t1.hover and #t2.hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know if there is some timeout working and stop it first. Here is your solution:

```
$(function(){
    var to;
    var $tb1 = $('#text-box1');

    $tb1.on('mouseenter', function(){
        if( to !== undefined ) return;
        var $this = $(this);
        to = setTimeout(function(){
            $this.text('The text changed!');
            to = undefined;
        }, 500);

    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        if( to !== undefined ) return;
        var $this = $(this);
        to = setTimeout(function(){
            $this.text('The previous Text');
            to = undefined;
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

[Check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/rbqm73t7/)